# Nonclustered Index on date columns used for BETWEEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table used for fiscal Periods that has a start and end date for when the period ends and begins. I use this table to determine when transactions have occurred for services and revenue has been collected in a query such as...

```
SELECT p.PeriodID, p.FiscalYear, SUM(t.Amount) AS Revenue
FROM Transactions t
JOIN Period p ON t.TransactionDate BETWEEN p.PeriodStart AND p.PeriodEnd
```

My question is, would it be beneficial to create a nonclustered index on the Period table for the date column? If so, should the index include both `PeriodStart` and `PeriodEnd` or just the `PeriodStart` column.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is not a right or wrong answer here. It depends...how many rows in the Period table? How much of the population would be returned? Is this query currently slow?

Comment: There will be 12 rows for each year starting at year 2008 currently. So only a few are currently used but I have the table built out to the year 2030 currently

Comment: Having start and end  in the index would eliminate the need to hit the actual table, so this should increase the performance, but I can't imagine by much

Comment: One might guess from your earlier reply that each row covers a single calendar month. If so, it might make more sense to eliminate `PeriodEnd` and use a calculated value with an open interval: `p.PeriodStart <= t.TransactionDate and t.TransactionDate < DateAdd( month, 1, p.PeriodStart )`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will suggest you to create index on both the columns,

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Period
  ON Period (PeriodStart, PeriodEnd)
  include (PeriodID, FiscalYear);
```

`Include` columns will help you to avoid the Lookup from Heap

creating index only on `PeriodStart` will not be useful